# Why isn't transition for my input forms working?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have tried to add transitions to my input forms but it doesn't work. I've read a lot of stack overflow posts but they haven't worked for me. A person said that it's because input has `display: none` but even after changing it, it still didn't work. I tried to be more specific when using `transition` but that didn't work. So I'm not sure how to fix this issue. The transition applies to the button but not to the input forms.

https://codepen.io/i-am-programming/pen/gOmydqv

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Store</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us </a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="login">Log In</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="username info" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="pass info" />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" />
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: url("images/background.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  align-items: center;
}

.login {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

input {
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

input:hover {
  width: 400px;
}

.username {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your code in text and link are different. Secondly you can't use transition on display cause it's not animatable. You cna use opacity and visibility instead of display. If we come to our question..

You want to get bigger input place when user get hover it right? So in your example your input does not has any width and when you hover it you want to get a transition. For this you need to add a width value to your input so it will know where the change began and what you want at the end. Meanwhile the time you passed is your time attribute on your transition. So

```
input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: none;
   transition: 0.3s;
}


input:hover {
  width: 400px;
}
```

It will know that when user hover on it, it will grow to 400px from 300px in 0.3s. That's it. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `transition` property in the `input`, it will be like this:

```
input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

input:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
```

[Read more of the CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't specify the width of your input

[image]